# Export each array item into a separate variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is it possible to gather each array variable and place it into its own variable. Sort of like this:

```
$array = array('music', 'video_games', 'photos', 'movies');
$count = count($array);
$i = 0;

while ($i < $count) {
    $array_val_1 = $array[0]; 
    $i++
}
```

`$array_val_1` and `$array[0]` would have to increment each time the while loop goes around so it would be `$array_val_2` and `$array[1]`

How would I do this. Because I have an array of checkboxes, I won't know how variables there will be in the array.

Comment: "But I want to put everyone of those array items into separate variables so that I perform other functions with them." You mean SQL columns?

Comment: Also, some code would be helpful.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Yes, I want to perform SQL queries with them

Comment: why is it so hard to write `$array[0]`, `$array[1]`? You do NOT want to pollute your variable name space with a zillion pointless variable names. `$array_val_1` is far far harder to work with than `$array[1]`.

Comment: @MarcB The problem is that I don't know if there is a `$array[1]` or `$array[2]` because everything is dynamic, I don't know how many checkboxes the user checked. I don't want to write `if (isset($array[1])) {$array1 = $array[1];}` for every checkbox I have. I'm just wondering if an easier way is possible. If there isn't an easier way, that's fine too.

Comment: `foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $key => $val) { .... }`. `<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[nameofcheckbox]" value="foo" />`. done

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). Example from docs:

```
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array);

echo "$color, $size, $shape";
```

Comment: my array looks like this though         ( [0] => music [1] => movies [2] => photo's [3] => animals [4] => life )

Comment: well then your array is not from a html form. maybe add more details to your question. also, the use of an apostrophe in a plural word (like photo's) is known as a grocer's apostrophe, and is incorrect and unnecessary. it's just "photos"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You shouldn't. There is a reason why arrays exists and if you need them to put into seperate variables, it means you software design is bad. Whatever you want to do, you can also do it with Arrays. Maybe you can post your usecase here.

Apart from this, there are so called `Variable variables`, but you really should not use them. It looks something like that:

```
$a = 'foo';
$$a = 'bar';
echo $foo; // returns 'bar'
```